# Gradebook: Python

Tags: python

I'm stuck on writing this program. These are the instructions that were given to us.

1. As per the guidelines at the top of the assignment you may NOT import any modules. This
   includes the statistics module.
2. The user should be displayed with a list of options from 1 to 5
3. If the user chooses 1 they should be prompted to enter a student's name and grade
4. If the student does not appear in the grade book, the student and the grade should be
   added to the grade book
5. If the student is already in the grade book their grade should be changed to the value
   given
6. If the user chooses 2 they should be prompted to enter a student's name.
7. That student should be removed from the grade book
8. If the student is not in the grade book then the grade book should not be modified
   but also no error should be displayed.
9. If the user chooses 3 the names and grades of all students should be displayed in
   alphabetical order
10. If the user chooses 4 the following statistics for the course should be displayed: Mean,
    Median, and Mode
11. The median is the middle number in a list of sorted numbers
12. The mode is the value that appears most often
13. If more there are 2 or more more numbers that appear most often then you may display any of them.
14. If the user chooses 5 the program should terminate
15. If any other option is chosen the program should tell the user that it does not recognize
    the option and ask the user for another choice.
16. All inputs besides the command choice will be valid.
17. You do not have to match the exact number of spaces I have in my output when
    displaying grades and course statistics but there needs to be at least 1 space.
18. Hint: Break the problem down into small functions that each tackle one part of the
    problem. For example have one function for inserting a student into the grade book, another for calculating the mean, etc.

This is what I have so far and there are a few errors:

```
def menuprint():
    print('1. Add/modify student grade.\n')
    print('2. Delete student grade\n')
    print('3. Print student grades\n')
    print('4. Display the course statistics\n')
    print('5. Quit\n')

menuprint()
choice = 0
students = []
grades = []

def addmodify():
    name_points = input('Enter name and points: ')
    nameGrade_list = name_points.split()
    name = nameGrade_list[0]
    points = nameGrade_list[1]
    students.append(name)
    grades.append([points])
def stat():
    for i in range(0,len(students)):
        print("NAME:", students[i])
        print ("GRADES:", grades [i])
def mean(list):
    sum = 0
    floatNums = [float(x) for x in list]
    return sum(floatNums) / len(list)

while choice !=5:
    choice = int(input('Your choice: '))
    if choice == 1:
        addmodify()
        print('Enter name and points:')
    elif choice == 2:
        name = input('Enter name to delete:')
        students.remove(name)



    elif choice == 3:
        gradelist()
        print ('SS')

    elif choice == 4:
        print('Mean', mean(grades))
```

Comment: What specifically you want to ask? SO is not code writing service

Comment: What problem are you getting any error or that sort of things

Comment: Whenever I try to obtain the mean I get this message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shwetadash/Desktop/grades.py", line 45, in <module>
    print('Mean', mean(grades))
  File "/Users/shwetadash/Desktop/grades.py", line 26, in mean
    floatNums = [float(x) for x in list]
  File "/Users/shwetadash/Desktop/grades.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    floatNums = [float(x) for x in list]
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: `list` is a built-in function and shouldn't be used as an identifier anywhere.  The same goes for `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mean(num_list):
    sum = 0
    floatNums = [float(x) for x in num_list]
    return sum(floatNums) / len(num_list)
```

should fix it. `list` is a keyword and cannot be used anywhere in your code as a variable.